# How to pulse text color dynamically from an array of colors?

Tags: css, typescript, angular7, ionic4

I have a `<span [innerHTML]="myHTML" [className]="myColor"></span>` I need to the innerHTML text to infinitely change from one color to another. The number of colors can vary by quite a bit so if possible I don't want to write out a bunch of CSS animations.

I tried using an `async` function with a `while` loop like this:
        `async colorChangeFunc(colors: string[]) {
          while(this.flagCalcComplete) {
           for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
              this.myColor = colors[i];
              setTimeout(null, 1000);
            }
          }
       }`

Where `colors` is an array of strings that correspond to a CSS class. However, I misunderstood how `async` works in TS and it of course crashed the browser.

Comment: do you want to change color each 1s?

Comment: `async` for something that never finishes? That doesn't seem to make any sense. async is so your code waits for asynchronous code before proceeding to the next line. You seem to understand that, so you should try it without async and post a different question if it doesn't work

Comment: @לבנימלכה something like that

Comment: @JuanMendes right, I was thinking that async would start a new thread. I'm not very familiar with TS yet.

Answer (score 1):

Use `i * 1000` in loop and set `style.color`

[See working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-fp3say?file=src/app/app.component.html)

**HTML**

```
<span [style.color]="myColor">Hello angular</span>
```

**TS**

```
   for (let i = 0; i < this.colors.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(()=>{
         this.myColor = this.colors[i];
        }, i * 1000);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This works, but it only changes the color once. I need to it to keep cycling through the colors. – alex87 33 mins ago

Comment: Thanks, but I think you misunderstood. After it reaches the last color I need it to go back to the first color and cycle through all the colors again.

Comment: I have solved it. It's not very elegant but I wrote a custom class and animation for each(10) possible color combinations.

Comment: I did not find solution because the `while` loop make my computer fail... :/